# Pass constant to super constructor

Tags: scala

How can I pass a constant from a sub class to a super constructor? Something like:

```
class SubClass extends SuperClass(Const) {
    val Const = ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constants are usually placed in [companion objects](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html), so you can do it as follows:

```
class SubClass extends SuperClass(SubClass.Const)

object SubClass {
  val Const = ...
}
```

Comment: "Use a companion object for methods and values which are not specific to instances of the companion class." Thanks for the hint/link!